# Server 2012 R2 - Can't access remote 2012 server in "all servers"

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, remote-access, workgroup

This is a scenario set up for MCSA training in my homelab, not an enterprise environment.

I'm trying to make changes to add roles to a virtual machine (VM workstation) Server 2012 R2 (running in bridged mode, meaning it gets dynamic IP from physical default gateway dhcp server) from my main Server 2012 R2 physical server from Server Manager, All Servers.

I add the remote server, TESTSERVER1, via manage->add servers and it shows up as such in "All Servers":
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8tvw.png

Here are the error messages produced: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB2Np.png

The main physical server, APOLLO has a static IP but the VM server is dynamic. This is a 255.255.255.0 subnet.
This is a workgroup environment.

How can I gain access to TESTSERVER1 so I can make changes to it remotely. When I right click it, "add roles and features" and "restart server" are greyed out. I appreciate any insight, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article *[Configure Remote Management in Server Manager](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh921475.aspx)*.

You may need to enable Remote Management and enable any firewall exceptions by using this command from an elevated prompt:

`%windir%\system32\Configure-SMRemoting.exe -enable`